# Why isn't Digit Grouping working in Excel 2010 as defined in Regional & Language Setting?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, regional-settings

Just upgraded to Excel 2010 & Windows7.

Digit grouping setting defined as required (12,34,56,789) in `control panel>region & Language>Addl Setting>Digit Grouping`, but Excel is not showing digit grouping as defined in aforesaid setting. Excel is still showing as (123,456,789).

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What's the country selected?

Answer (score 0):

friends, I got the solution for my aforesaid problem.

It need to set in control panel>region & Language>Addl Setting>Digit Grouping (on "Numbers" tab) & as well as set in "CURRENCY" tab > DIGIT GROUPING... Now it is working fine on my system.